# Log4Net smtp appender only send email when error with full log(debug & info & error). Only when the application ends

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am trying to configure a smtp appender in the log4net.config file that I have. The problem is that I have looked all over the internet and cannot find how to send an email when an error occurs with all the other log information included such as info, debug, error, fatal. Only when the application ends (NOT every time an ERROR occurs).

So I only want to receive this email when:
  The application ends + 
  With all the log information (DEBUG, INFO, ERROR, FATAL) +
  Only if an ERROR has occured.

Elaborating some more this is because of the way I handle my exceptions in c sharp, with multiple level handling all over the place and so if an error occurs no matter how many times I only want to receive one email. Also I do not want to use multiple logs, but rather
just one in root.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SmtpAppender` cannot accomplish this on its own. So what I did was create another appender that to an appender of type `MemoryAppender`. I set a threshold on this logger to only include messages that should trigger the `SmtpAppender`, e.g. `Error`. We use this to later determine if we want to send the email which has more levels logged.

We don't actually care about the messages in the `MemoryAppender`--we just care that it contains messages at the end. The messages we get via email actually come from the `SmtpAppender`.

At the end of my program I check the memory appender to see if its GetEvents() contains any events. If so, I *do not* stop the `SmtpAppender` from running normally.

Log4Net configs for both appenders:

```xml
<appender name="ErrorHolder" type="log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender" >
    <onlyFixPartialEventData value="true" />
    <!-- if *any* message is logged with this level, the email appender will 
         be used with its own level -->
    <threshold value="ERROR" />
</appender>

<appender name="Email" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">    
    <!-- the level you want to see in the email IF ErrorHolder finds anything -->
    <threshold value="INFO"/> 
    <bufferSize value="512" />
    <lossy value="false" /> <!-- important! -->   
    <to value="name@domain.com" />
    <from value="name@domain.com" />
    <subject value="ERROR: subject" />
    <smtpHost value="smtpserver" />    
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
    </layout>    
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorHolder" />
  <appender-ref ref="Email" />
</root>
```

At the end of the app run this to disable the `SmtpAppender` if the `ErrorHolder` appender is empty:

```
// trigger loggers if errors occurred:
var memoryAppender = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository())
    .Root.Appenders.OfType<MemoryAppender>().FirstOrDefault();

if (memoryAppender != null && memoryAppender.GetEvents().Length == 0)
{
    // there was no error so don't email anything
    var smtpAppender = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository())
        .Root.Appenders.OfType<SmtpAppender>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (smtpAppender != null)
    {
        smtpAppender.Threshold = Level.Off;
        smtpAppender.ActivateOptions();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a fairly complex version of what I suggested in my solution.

Comment: Thats correct, you were right I did take your idea of checking at the end, thats true. But when in search of how to look inside appenders for certain level occurances (being here). I could not find any thing in regards to any appenders were I could get the events within them. So the only one I could find is a MemoryAppender and I used that.

Comment: Here a post about tracking down log4net problems:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems

Comment: Whao! This answer is still relevant today.  In an asp.net web mvc project, any log4net buffered messages that don't reach the BufferSize maximum are discarded when the web request ends.  I added the smtpAppender.Flush() code in the Application_EndRequest of global.asax and all is good now.  Thanks for the code @PashaImmortals

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an application configuration issue rather than a log4net configuration issue.    I would suggest putting a method in at the close of your application that emails you the log file if it detects that there is an error inside it.  You could either detect this error by flipping a global variable from false to true in every place where you log errors or you could wait until the end of your application and then read the log file to see if it contains errors.  The first method would be quicker at shutdown but it means modifying your code in multiple places.  The latter would allow you to just add one method but it might take longer in a large file.

A third option would be to send errors to a second log file (so they go two places) using log4net.  Then, when your application is closing and you are checking to see if you should email the log, just check for the existence of the error-only file.  If it exists, delete it (so it isn't there next time) and email the full log.

Comment: How do you check at the end of the program if any errors have occured what do you look for? in logger, appender?, what methods used and fields. Can you paste some code please.

Comment: I have found that you can run into file IO issues when trying to send the actual log file (another process has it open). Even if you flush the fileAppender, release the lock and copy it, I still ran into IO problems if log4Net was rolling the log files at the time.

Answer (score 0):

change treshold to Error. Also log 4net only sends the email when the app is clodes.you can send it earlier. but than you first need to copy it ( because the org file is still in use) and than you can email the copy.