# log4net is not logging out anything

Tags: c#, log4net

I am struggling to get anything to log out using log4net.  I have tried using code from various sources but still no joy.  Can someone please help me figure out why?

**Assembly.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

**MyClass.cs**

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

log.Info("Complete: "+result); // used when my "task" completes, is always called
```

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header value="[Your Header text here]" />
      <footer value="[Your Footer text here]" />
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] &lt;%property{auth}&gt; - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!-- Set the default logging level and add the active appenders -->
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>

</log4net>
```

One thing to note is that all this is withing one project.  The program running this is in a different project but all logging is done within this assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable log4net's internal debug output, to track down why it's not logging.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756241/61697) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a log4net section to your configuration in your Web.config or App.config?

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [log4net documentation for assembly attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) says this:

> Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
>   to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to
>   LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly
>   to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging
>   call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
>   certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**

Your logging however is in an external assembly already. This is a bit of an issue when using assembly attributes, I would recommend using [`XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(…)`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch_overloads.html) in your startup code instead.