# Log file not created in the appData in VSTO using log4net

Tags: vsto, log4net, log4net-configuration, office-addins

I have created an addin using VSTo 2010 and my application as soon as it starts, the folders are created in the AppData path. For my other windows desktop application, the log file is created as soon as the application starts up, and the same implementation is used for my addin also. Bu I am getting an error saying "Couuld not find part of the path". The file name is configured as `${APPDATA}\My Application\Project\My Project\ExcelLogs.log`. I have copied the Excel.exe.config to the programFilesx86-> Microsoft Office -> Office 14. And have added  `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` in the assemblyInfo class. The AppData path is configured as `m_strGeneralFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + Config.APPDATA_PATH;` But still as soon as the application starts i get the error.

Comment: See [how to track down log4net problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems)

Comment: @stuartd - nothing is logged in the file. i tried doing it

Comment: Could [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file.aspx) be the issue?

Comment: @stuartd - yes i changed the manifest path. It is working fine now.