# Log4net stopped logging to a file

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Here is the setup that we are using, not sure why this is not working.

**Class File:**

```
const string conpath = @"configfiles\log4net.config";

XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(conpath));
```

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"configfiles\log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>

  <!-- appender section -->
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%date{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}]: %message%newline%exception"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%m%n%exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
      <conversionPattern value=".\LogFiles\log" />
    </file>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value=" - yyyy.MM.dd'.txt'"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header value="[LOG FILE STARTED]&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;" />
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %message%newline" />
      <footer value="&#13;&#10;[LOG FILE FINISHED]&#13;&#10;" />
    </layout>
  </appender>


  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: See [how to track down log4net problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems)

Comment: Also, you should use either an assembly attribute or `XmlConfigurator.Configure` but there's no reason to use both. Are you sure your app has the rights to write to the log file?