# Log4net doesn't write to DB

Tags: c#, database, log4net, log4net-configuration

For the past few hours I've been trying to get a log to write to a table in a database.

After turning debugging on, I received the following error statement: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size

Here are my snippets:

Config section:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="loginLog"/>
      <appender-ref ref="maskyooLog"/>
      <appender-ref ref="bpelLog"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="bpelLog" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="server=***; uid=***; pwd=****; database=***" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.BPELLog ([UserName], [ProcessModeID], [CcCompanyNameID], [CcExpDate], 
                                                   [CcID], [CcOwnerID], [CcOwnerName], [InvoiceDate], [CustomerNo], 
                                                   [SumWithDue], [SumWithoutDue], [PaymentTypeID], [TaxRegistrationNum], [TrxUniqueID], [SalesPerson]) 
                          VALUES (@UserName, @ProcessModeID, @CcCompanyNameID, @CcExpDate, @CcID, @CcOwnerID, @CcOwnerName,
                                 @InvoiceDate, @CustomerNo, @SumWithDue, @SumWithoutDue, @PaymentTypeID, 
                                 @TaxRegistrationNum, @TrxUniqueID, @SalesPerson)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@InvoiceDate" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@ProcessModeID" />
        <dbType value="Int32" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{ProcessModeID}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@PaymentTypeID" />
        <dbType value="Int32" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{PaymentTypeID}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CustomerNo"/>
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CustomerNo}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@TaxRegistrationNum"/>
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{TaxRegistrationNum}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@SalesPerson"/>
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{SalesPerson}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@TrxUniqueID"/>
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{TrxUniqueID}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CcOwnerName" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CcOwnerName}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CcOwnerID" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CcOwnerID}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CcID" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CcID}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CcExpDate" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CcExpDate}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@UserName" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{UserName}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CcCompanyNameID" />
        <dbType value="Int32" />
        <size value="15" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CcCompanyNameID}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@SumWithoutDue" />
        <dbType value="decimal" />
        <size value="20" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{SumWithoutDue}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@SumWithDue" />
        <dbType value="decimal" />
        <size value="20" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{SumWithDue}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
```

And the Class:

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.Util.SystemInfo.NullText = null;

            GlobalContext.Properties["UserName"] = userName;
            GlobalContext.Properties["ProcessModeID"] = processModeId;
            GlobalContext.Properties["CcCompanyNameID"] = ccCompanyNameId;
            GlobalContext.Properties["CcExpDate"] = cCExpDate;
            GlobalContext.Properties["CcID"] = ccId;
            GlobalContext.Properties["CcOwnerID"] = ccOwnerId;
            GlobalContext.Properties["CcOwnerName"] = ccOwnerName;
            GlobalContext.Properties["InvoiceDate"] = invoiceDate;
            GlobalContext.Properties["CustomerNo"] = customerNo;
            GlobalContext.Properties["SumWithDue"] = sumWithDue;
            GlobalContext.Properties["SumWithoutDue"] = sumWithoutDue;
            GlobalContext.Properties["PaymentTypeID"] = paymentTypeId;
            GlobalContext.Properties["TaxRegistrationNum"] = taxRegistrationNum;
            GlobalContext.Properties["TrxUniqueID"] = trxUniqueId;
            GlobalContext.Properties["SalesPerson"] = salesPerson;

            log.Debug(string.Format("UserName: {0}, ProcessModeID: {1}, CcCompanyNameID: {2}, CcExpDate: {3}, CcID: {4}, CcOwnerID: {5}, InvoiceDate: {6}, CustomerNo: {7}, SumWithDue: {8}, SumWithoutDue: {9}, PaymentTypeID: {10},"
                                    + "TaxRegistrationNum: {11}, TrxUniqueID: {12}, SalesPerson: {13}", userName, processModeId, ccCompanyNameId, cCExpDate, ccId, ccOwnerId, ccOwnerName, invoiceDate, customerNo, sumWithDue, sumWithoutDue,
                                    paymentTypeId, taxRegistrationNum, trxUniqueId, salesPerson));
```

No errors are shown in Output window.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try turning on internal debugging to see what happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, I've turned debugging on and received the following error: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving the size to all your string parameters as below? The size should match the actual size in the database.

```
     <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@CustomerNo"/>
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CustomerNo}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm one step forward, I need to set the precision and scale of my decimals, could you help with the syntax please?

Comment: Generally for the fixed size data types(int,decimal,bit etc) you dont need to specifiy the size

Comment: Well, I did append the scale and precision, it did work. Now I'm getting System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by Adding the precision and scale to my decimals and adding size to strings. In addition, I missed one colon in my query.
Thanks guys for your support!