# log4net multiple adonetappender each with custom fields

Tags: log4net

Im trying to use log4net to create logs in two different tables. The first adonetappender will log into a table called 'log' and should be the standard id, date, thread, level etc etc. The second adonetappender needs to log to a table with three columns called 'usageLog' and only needs to log the date/time, and two additional string values. I cant for the life of me figure it out. What do I need to do? Below is my config so far. I'm not sure if its correct and I dont know how to use this in the program.

```
<log4net>
<logger additivity="false" name="Log">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="LogAppender" />
</logger>
<logger additivity="false" name="UsageLog">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="UsageLogAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="LogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <!-- Causes errors to be written immediately - default is 100 -->
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=dummy;initial catalog=dummy;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=dummy;Password=dummy" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>

<appender name="UsageLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <!-- Causes errors to be written immediately - default is 100 -->
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=dummy;initial catalog=dummy;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=dummy;Password=dummy" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO UsageLog ([Date],[ManDesc],[ModDesc]) VALUES (@log_date, @man_desc, @model_desc)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@man_desc" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{man_desc}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@model_desc" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{model_desc}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Comment: It is a bit hard to see what's wrong, could you check the following: does your log work when you write to a text file on the disk? if not, go through the configuration steps for log4net again to see what may be wrong. If it does, check whether the credentials are right, and if a command line call to your sql db works from the machine your app is deployed to.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are wanting to log the same messages to two different tables with different columns.  If this is true it seems like you are missing the root logger:

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="UsageLogAppender" />
</root>
```

If you are however are declaring your loggers like this in the code and only want those specific loggers to log to these different tables that is a different story:

```
private readonly static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("Log");
private readonly static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("UsageLog");
```

By declaring your loggers this way in the code your above configuration should still work.  If you are not declaring your logs this way nothing will be logged.  It's always helpful to turn on log4net logging though too:

[How to track down log4net problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems)