# Two loggers writing to same file

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I configured two loggers and want them to simultaneously log to Event Log and text file, but they both logging to text.
Here is my configuration file:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="NavRiskFileImportError.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="{%level}{%date} – %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <param name="ApplicationName" value="NavriskFromExcel" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
<!--loggers-->
    <logger name="FileLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="EventLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

In my application I have:

```
private static  ILog logger= LogManager.GetLogger("FileLogger");
private static  ILog eventLogger= LogManager.GetLogger("EventLogger");
```

But both loggers are writing data to the file and nothing in the event log. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify `additivity="false"` on the individual loggers, otherwise they inherit the appenders from the root logger:

> Additivity is set to true by default, that is children inherit the
>   appenders of their ancestors by default. If this variable is set to
>   false then the appenders found in the ancestors of this logger are not
>   used ([source](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html))

So that would mean:

```
<logger name="EventLogger" additivity="false">
```

That explains why both are writing to the file.

So the remaining question is why the EventLogAppender isn't working. You can check for configuration errors with this code:

```
var messages = LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages.Cast<LogLog>();

if (messages.Any())
{
     string message = messages.Aggregate("Log4net Configuration Errors: "
                                        + Environment.NewLine,
            (s, log) => s + log.Message + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And if that doesn't show anything, [enable log4net internal debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756241/43846) and check the output.

Edit: the documentation states [EventLogAppender will fail if you try to write using an event source that doesn't exist unless it is running with local administrator privileges](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender.html) but the event source needs to be created by an elevated process, or an [installer](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog) - the event source has to be created once per machine.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, now it is writing only to the file nothing in the Event Log and no errors

Comment: My guess would be permissions. Is this a web application?

Comment: No, this is console, running under domain admin account

Comment: Try running it in as Administrator, in case it's trying to create an event source - I've not used log4net to log to the event log, but I've seen that in other contexts.