# Log4net does not log on an XP machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration

This is my first attempt of using Log4net. I have implemented my app.config as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="NEALogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>

      <file value="C:\Logs\NEA_Log\NEALog.log"/>

      <appendToFile value="true"/>

      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>

      <datePattern value="&quot;.&quot;yyyyMMdd"/>

      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>

      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SystemLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <file value="C:\System_Log\SystemLog.log"/>

      <appendToFile value="true"/>

      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>

      <datePattern value="&quot;.&quot;yyyyMMdd"/>

      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>

      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL"></level>

      <appender-ref ref="SystemLogger"></appender-ref>"
      <!--<appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"></appender-ref>-->
    </root>
    <logger name="NEALogger" additivity="False">
      <level value="ALL"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="NEALogger"></appender-ref>
    </logger>

  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have used [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)] in my assemblyInfo.cs.

I have tried both appenders on my win7 laptop and everything works fine. I built an installer and installed it on an xp machine with .net4.0 and nothing logs. The log files are not created.

I instantiate the loggers thus:

`private static readonly ILog neaLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("NEALogger");`

and use it thus:

`neaLogger.InfoFormat(logMessage);`

Is there anything specific that I need to be doing to make this work on an XP machine? I looked at the permissions and have set full control of the folders etc to everyone and still nothing.

This is pretty frustrating as it works from my laptop running win7 and .net4.5.

I'm sure this is set to.net4.0. Do I need to use a different version?

Hoping someone has the answer.

Steve

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the installer? Can you try installing on a Windows 7 machine to test that?