# Save Log Information in Database with log4net and NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, log4net

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56111/Save-Log-Information-in-Database-with-log-net-and) tutorial and was able to get both of the projects working with my instance of sql server 2012:

However, when I included **HLogger** project within *my* solution (instead of using it together with the sample project above), it did work.

The following is a code snippet that worked for me when running it from the provided sample project; however, when I added this library to my own solution, it did not work.

```
    ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("NHibernateLogging");
    log.Error("Error!", new Exception("Exception123"));
    log.Warn("Warning");
```

Nothing happened. Nothing was thrown. The database was not populated. I am using the same hibernate.cfg.xml file as the one provided (and worked in conjuncture with the "sample project"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Server=------.net;database=mydb;user id=myuser;password=sdofjosidfjoijsf;persist security info=true;
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">
      true
    </property>
    <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The **only** change was to the app.config file. It used to be:

```
<section name="log4net"
  type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net-net-1.0" />
```

and now it is:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

The reason for this is that I cannot have multiple versions of log4net in the same solution, and I do not have a choice on my current log4net version due to its capabilities with being able to log the version 2 of masstransit with msmq.

The projects in the codeproject site were created for .NET 3.5, whereas my solution is .net 4.5.

**How do I diagnose the reason for not being able to log anything with log4net in a database?**

Comment: You need to enable [log4net's internal debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with,

1. See if the issue is with Log4Net, try adding a FileAppender for the same configuration and see if works
2. If log4net works then next one is to check the Appender configuration, specially Double check namesapaces of classes / assembly names