# Problem logging using log4net to elasticsearch 8 with C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a simple c# prgram trying to log to elastic search 8.6, elasticsearch and kibana are up and running. i can send logs using curl and I can see my logs in kibana. I can't send logs using my c# app using log4net. there's no visible error but the logs are not in elastic search.
Here is my code and configuration:
log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Be sure this configSections block is immediately after the <configuration> opening tag! -->
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <log4net debug="true">
        <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
                <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
                <levelMax value="FATAL" />
            </filter>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ElasticSearchAppender" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
            <connectionString value="Scheme=http;Server=localhost;Index=my-index-000001;Port=9200;User=user;Pwd=myPassword;rolling=true;" />
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.5.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is my c# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            // Load the log4net configuration
            ILoggerRepository repository = LogManager.CreateRepository("MyApp");

            // Load the log4net configuration
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

            // Get the logger for the current class
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(repository.Name, typeof(Program));
            log.Logger.Repository.Threshold = Level.Info;

            // Log some events
            log.Info("Application started.");
            log.Debug("Application started debugging.");
            log.Warn("This is a warning message.");
            log.Error("Oh my god.");

            // Wait for user input
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Any one knows how to get it working?

Comment: any hints from your app logs about possible misconfigurations?

Comment: No, the output seems ok

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with log4net, but do you mean you have log4net logs mentioning a successful connection with elasticsearch? or any other log4net logs?

Comment: There are no errors in the output, and I see my logs in Console. I got this working with Serilog, but I need to use log4net

Comment: [Enable log4net internal debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems) and see what it says

Comment: No errors are reported

Comment: were you able to resolve this?