why doesn't Log4net work when using dotnet run?
I've got log4net working when I run using a debugger in vs code or rider, but on both windows and osx I don't see any logging output when using dotnet run.
Here is my logger config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
    <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
    <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">

        <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="AWSCloudWatch" type="AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender,AWS.Logger.Log4net">
        <LogGroup>athena/scanrunner/multi-workers</LogGroup>
        <Region>us-west-2</Region>

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
    <root>
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="A1" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>

I am using XmlConfigurator to load the config.
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
        var worker = new WorkerService();
        worker.Start().Wait();
    }


Where is the config file in relationship to the working directory and the location of the binary you are running?

both in the bin/Debug/net7.0/ folder.

Using log4net’s internal debugging mechanism might help - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems

Is there any other logging settings inside this project?

No.
(Wasting 15 chars because this site is a nightmare)

Did you try log4net’s internal debugging?

worker.Start().Wait(); - don't do that. Make your Main a public static async Task Main(string[] args) and then await worker.Start();. You'll probably also need to keep the program running after that, so any logs have the chance to be written before the program terminates.
